# Aggregation Mongo DB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation

Can someone explain why this does not work?

```
// First Document: 
_id: 5fb3e506e32b1d3e2019ebc6
CourseName:"Construction Of Interactive Systems"
userId:"5fb39e3d11eaad3e30cfb1b0"

_id: 5fb3e8819c3cf13f301c17ba
CourseName: "Design Of Interactive Systems"
userId:"5fb39e3d11eaad3e30cfb1b0"

// Second Document: 
_id: 5fb39e3d11eaad3e30cfb1b0
username "Tobias"

_id: 5fb3d151cc726630c0d62796
username: "Thor"

dbo.collection('Courses').aggregate([
            { $lookup:
                    {
                        from: 'users',
                        localField: 'userId',
                        foreignField: '_id',
                        as: 'orderdetails'
                    }
            }
        ])
```

I just get empty arrays from this aggregation temp. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: make sure is `userId` type object id?

Comment: It's not. It comes from mongoose req.user.id. How can I parse it to ObjectId?

Comment: you can convert string id to object id `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id)`